# Not able to cache using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm using Hibernate for my second level cache(Ehcache), but second level cache is working only for session.load type, when I write my own query, its not working.

### Not working table

```
String hql = "FROM Personalisation E WHERE E.userId = "+id;
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<?> results = query.list();
```

### Working other table

```
Employee emp = session.load(Employee.class, id);
```

### My ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<ehcache>  
<defaultCache   
maxElementsInMemory="100"   
eternal="false"   
timeToIdleSeconds="120"   
timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  

<cache name="com.intu.Employee"   
maxElementsInMemory="100"   
eternal="false"   
timeToIdleSeconds="10"   
timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  

<cache name="com.intu.Personalisation"   
maxElementsInMemory="100"   
eternal="false"   
timeToIdleSeconds="10"   
timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  

</ehcache>
```